# How to get vitest/v8 to ignore or correctly cover the script tag of vue component

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuejs3, vitest

All my vue component files start with `<script setup lang="ts">` when using vitest with v8 for coverage, this line is not covered, and the branch is not covered.

How to get the coverage to be correct?
And is this a bug? And of whom?

Is it possible to get it to cover that line?
Or is it possible to ignore all script setup tags?

[image]